# Issue getting items in array to display

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting issues getting items to display from a hook. I console logged the hook prior to making the  tags and there is data saved, yet I can't display it. Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SubmissionForm from "../SubmissionForm/SubmissionForm.component";

const ItemList = () => {
    
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
    
    const addItem = e => {
        if(!e.text || /^\s*$/.test(e.text)) {
            return
        }
        
        const addItemsToList = [e,...tasks];
        setTasks(addItemsToList);
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <SubmissionForm onSubmit={addItem} />
            <h1>{tasks.length > 0 ? tasks : 'No Tasks'}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ItemList;
```

I'm not sure how to get the items in the hook array to display in the H1. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, to begin with you are trying to print an array as a string. I think you should focus on JavaScript basics first before getting into React.

Answer (score 0):

No worries all. I figured it out.

Since the item is an array, you need to render an option for each item stored in that array. This is the fix:

```js
 {tasks.length ? tasks.map(task => <h1>{task.text}</h1>) : 'No Tasks'}
```

I set this so if there is something in the array, it will then print out all the items in tasks into a h1, else it will show "No Tasks".